# What is the use of distance matrix in clustering algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, distance

I found a C library for clustering and I was reading about the distance matrix [here](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/%7Emdehoon/software/cluster/cluster.pdf): it says:

> The first step in clustering problems is usually to calculate the distance matrix. This matrix
> contains all the distances between the items that are being clustered.

If I have a cloud of data (I'm studying web traffic and I'm trying to classify it not with known ports or payload inspection, but with some kind of pattern recognition of collected data such as total number of packets, mean packet size, mean payload size excluding headers, number of bytes transfered), how should the distance matrix be set?

The quote says

> This matrix contains all the distances between the items that are being clustered

so some kind of clustering has already been done? I think I'm missing something...

Comment: The very word "cluster" connotes a set of things that are mutually "close."  It is up to *you* to determine what you mean by "close"--but that determination does not imply any clustering has yet been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever source that is, it is wrong, and probably not of high quality.

> The first step in clustering problems is usually to calculate the distance matrix.

I disagree that this "usually" is the first step. There are plenty of examples (e.g. k-means, DBSCAN, SLINK, EM/Gaussian Mixture modeling, ...) that **do not need a distance matrix at all**.

In fact, **for large data, computing a full distance matrix will kill you** - any algorithm that requires a distance matrix is not scalable to large data.

But you also stopped reading after the first step. At this point, no clustering has been done yet. But if you use an algorithm that *does* use a distance matrix (say, the naive $O(n^3)$ algorithm for hierarchical clustering) then you have already done a substantial amount of computation. While this part is only $O(n^2)$, it is already very expensive.